# Array Grouping - How to structure a api response

Tags: php, arrays, merge, spotify

Okay the question is a bid oddly said because im not sure how to explain it well in a short title.

So here is My Idea (Just so it make more sense)

I am messing out with the spotify api and trying to save all of my songs (export them) since i have a lot of songs and if somehow spotify messes something up and everything goes bad, I Still have a list of all of my songs.

So here is my Problem.

I managed to get all of the songs and Artits names.
The Prbolem is i have "more" artists then songs since there 1 or more people on on song(features)

Here is some code, which probably clears things up...

```
 $tracksData = $this->getAllPlaylistTracksData('PLAYLISTID');

        var_dump($tracksData);

        $allTracksName = [];

        foreach ($tracksData as $trackData) {
            $artistsData = $trackData->track->artists;

            var_dump($artistsData);

            $allTracksName[] = $trackData->track->name;

        }

 return $allTracksName;
```

Here are the two dump outputs:

All of the Song Data:

```
array (size=2135)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'added_at' => string '2014-01-06T12:26:52Z' (length=20)
      public 'added_by' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'external_urls' => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              ...
          public 'href' => string '' (length=43)
          public 'id' => string '' (length=10)
          public 'type' => string 'user' (length=4)
          public 'uri' => string 'spotify:user:' (length=23)
      public 'is_local' => boolean false
      public 'primary_color' => null
      public 'track' => 
        object(stdClass)[16]
          public 'album' => 
            object(stdClass)[9]
              ...
          public 'artists' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'available_markets' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'disc_number' => int 1
          public 'duration_ms' => int 255093
          public 'episode' => boolean false
          public 'explicit' => boolean false
          public 'external_ids' => 
            object(stdClass)[19]
              ...
          public 'external_urls' => 
            object(stdClass)[20]
              ...
          public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3zKST4nk4QJE77oLjUZ0Ng' (length=56)
          public 'id' => string '3zKST4nk4QJE77oLjUZ0Ng' (length=22)
          public 'is_local' => boolean false
          public 'name' => string 'Hey Brother' (length=11)
          public 'popularity' => int 22
          public 'preview_url' => null
          public 'track' => boolean true
          public 'track_number' => int 3
          public 'type' => string 'track' (length=5)
          public 'uri' => string 'spotify:track:3zKST4nk4QJE77oLjUZ0Ng' (length=36)
      public 'video_thumbnail' => 
        object(stdClass)[21]
          public 'url' => null
  1 =>
```

All of the Artits Data:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[17]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'Avicii' (length=6)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6' (length=37)
**array (size=1)**
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[33]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'Arctic Monkeys' (length=14)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH' (length=37)
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[52]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[51]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6yTYR09WCvsgdnurDW4WQo' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6yTYR09WCvsgdnurDW4WQo' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '6yTYR09WCvsgdnurDW4WQo' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'DJ Antoine' (length=10)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:6yTYR09WCvsgdnurDW4WQo' (length=37)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[54]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[53]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3yBEHAINorE3uSvsCmyCwQ' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3yBEHAINorE3uSvsCmyCwQ' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '3yBEHAINorE3uSvsCmyCwQ' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'Mad Mark' (length=8)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:3yBEHAINorE3uSvsCmyCwQ' (length=37)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[56]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[55]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1o9x7ez0NvhDb7gBqrYnUj' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1o9x7ez0NvhDb7gBqrYnUj' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '1o9x7ez0NvhDb7gBqrYnUj' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'B-Case' (length=6)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:1o9x7ez0NvhDb7gBqrYnUj' (length=37)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[58]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[57]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/5FTpdDUA9cksspPW5Ix78g' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5FTpdDUA9cksspPW5Ix78g' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '5FTpdDUA9cksspPW5Ix78g' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'U-Jean' (length=6)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:5FTpdDUA9cksspPW5Ix78g' (length=37)
K:\programming\development\spotify-backup\Utility\Manager.php:49:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[74]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[73]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1h6Cn3P4NGzXbaXidqURXs' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1h6Cn3P4NGzXbaXidqURXs' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '1h6Cn3P4NGzXbaXidqURXs' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'Swedish House Mafia' (length=19)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:1h6Cn3P4NGzXbaXidqURXs' (length=37)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[76]
      public 'external_urls' => 
        object(stdClass)[75]
          public 'spotify' => string 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2auikkNYqigWStoHWK1Grq' (length=54)
      public 'href' => string 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2auikkNYqigWStoHWK1Grq' (length=57)
      public 'id' => string '2auikkNYqigWStoHWK1Grq' (length=22)
      public 'name' => string 'John Martin' (length=11)
      public 'type' => string 'artist' (length=6)
      public 'uri' => string 'spotify:artist:2auikkNYqigWStoHWK1Grq' (length=37)
```

As you can tell the second dump is my playlist 1:1

[image]

Now my problem is that im not sure how to group them, yes i tried iterating through them like so

```
foreach ($artistsData as $artistData) {
                $allArtistsName[] = $artistData->name;
            }
```

But that just leaves me with two massive array, that are diffrent sizes since there are "more" artits then songs.

Does anyone have any idea how i could solve this?

EDIT:

I would like to have something like this

```
0 => [
songName => i
Artists = > x y z
]
```

Comment: Because then i just have all the artits and they are not grouped with the correct songs, i would just have 2 arrays one witht the title and one with the artists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in your `var_dump` that every artistes is found in the array of his song - so you can add another loop inside the songs array and extract the artists list of each song:

```
 $tracksData = $this->getAllPlaylistTracksData('PLAYLISTID');

 $songs = [];

 foreach ($tracksData as $trackData) {
     $artistsNamesForSong = []; // init new artists array for each song
     foreach($trackData->track->artists as $artist) {
         $artistsNamesForSong[] = $artist->name;
     }

     $songs[] = ["songName" => , "Artists" => $artistsNamesForSong];
 }

 return $songs;
```

Comment: Where are the {} from the second foreach ?

Comment: Added them - you are right - it is better practice to use them. However, just for aline - when not scope for `foreach` only the first line after is count